# Asp.net MVC4 on Azure keeps looking for MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I am running a webapi and getting the following error,

```
{
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.",
"ExceptionType": "System.IO.FileNotFoundException",
"StackTrace": null
}
```

I am running on MVC4, VS.NET 2012 locally with no problem, and in my web.config, I've also redirected

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

I have other web api but it's running fine, this is the only one giving me problem, nothing special in the method either. Any idea or similar experience?

Comment: May it be that you have another web.config somewhere else in the folder tree like in Views subfolder or the like?

Comment: Check the file versions of all your dependent assemblies - it could be you have referenced a 3.0 assembly. RDP and check the `/bin` directly or open up the `cspkg` to verify.